# Check/Uncheck using wild card

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have 12 checkboxes all having id's like this

> checkbox-1
>
> checkbox-2
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> checkbox-12

Now I want to get checkbox-1 using jquery so I did like this

```
var p =1;
$('#checkbox-'+p)
```

the thing is it gives me the `checkbox-1` , `checkbox-11` and `checkbox-12`. I just want to get `checkbox-1`. Can somebody tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong

Comment: Can you post some of your actual HTML, lookups by `id` should only return one element

Comment: @RobM. actual jQuery code.

Comment: Whatever, this seems to be a situation where the mere use of IDs is highly inconvenient.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/81xa175u/1/, something else is going on here

Comment: I agree with @RobM. Something strange is going on, could you post the HTML, please?